# Including Android headers when using CMake to build

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I using CMake to build a native library .so for Android. I have added the following.

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 21) # API level
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI arm64-v8a)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /path/to/android-ndk)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE gnustl_static)
```

However, I get the error that `#include <android/log.h>` was not found when make is run. I guessed that the preceding `set()` commands might have included the NDK libs and headers like `android/log.h` but clearly it is not so. What is the best way to include the headers and libs supplied by the NDK in CMake ?

Comment: Did you literally put `/path/to/android-ndk` for `CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK`, or did you put the correct path to where the NDK is located on your machine?

Comment: The actual path in my system was put.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use Android Studio to drive CMake. This is the easiest way to use the NDK CMake toolchain which will correctly set up the paths no matter which NDK you're using.

It is possible, but harder, to use NDK CMake toolchain without Android Studio. You'll need to pass the path to the NDK toolchain file to CMake at command-line when generating your project.

If you need to use the CMake android toolchain (as in your example) then it looks like you need to set include paths:
include_directories(/path/to/android-ndk/loglib)

Comment: I know Android studio does CMake well and I was hoping to replicate that. It must be using some systematic way to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: If you're not using Studio, you should use the CMake toolchain file that's included in the NDK. `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake`. Look at the top of that file for a list of other options.